# How to get other user events (respecting permissions) when using app-only approach in MS Graph API?

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi, outlook-calendar

I have an application that calls MS Graph API to get users' events. This app uses app-only auth mode (http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only). I can get events for every user, but I'd like to be able to get events for user `A` not as user `A` (so I get all events with all details)  but as user `B`, so I see `A`'s events respecting visibility of `A`'s calendar (i.e. see "busy" only when `B` has no access to event).

How to do it using Graph API and app-only auth mode?

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently possible with the app-only authorization flow. We're considering adding such functionality in the future though.

Comment: Thanks for response! I'd love to see it, as app-mode suppose to be a way of acting as a particular user, so it should be possible to see other people's calendars... Is this a way to achieve that in EWS API or any other API using app-mode?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use delegated permissions? This is the flow where an app is acting as a particular user. The 'only' in the name of the 'app-only' flow indicates that there is only app context, and specifically no user context. The app is supposed to have access to all users calendars when consented by tenant admin. When using the delegated permissions flow user B signs in and can access user A events via /v1.0/users/A/events - respecting visibility of A's calendar.

Comment: My app needs to act as any user, event not only currently logged in (e.g. one user can updates/cancel event that other created). So I cannot use user consent authentication, I need to allow it once (by admin) and them, act as any user. In Google Calendar API (using service account, counterpart of "app-only" mode) there is such feature, as there, this mode only delegates authentication to admin, but then, every action is in the context of some user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! In the pure app-only (client credentials) flow it's the app itself that is considered the principal performing an action: "The OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials Grant Flow permits a web service (a confidential client) to use its own credentials to authenticate when calling another web service, instead of impersonating a user" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx). There are scenarios where it would be useful to allow a highly privileged app to act as a user, but we don’t support that right now and there is no timeline yet for adding support.

Comment: by "we" (don't support that) you mean Graph API only or rather Office365 API? Any idea if it's doable using EWS API?

Comment: I meant both Graph and Office 365 REST APIs. I'm not familiar with EWS, but according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx that should be possible with the EWS impersonation feature: "Use impersonation when you have a service application that needs to access multiple mailboxes and "act as" the mailbox owner."